# Set the Entity Connection string in a different project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string

I want to place **Entities** and **Database** (here I used Sql Serve Ce) in a project, and use them in another project in the `same solution`.

**`I have problem setting the database location this way and the context is always null`**

`Project One` will have all the **database** , **ConnectionString** and **entities**

`Project Two` is the User project of the Entities defined in Project One

This is a Windows Forms Application
And the name of the Entity Connection Name is **dbEntitties**

The database is in the **root of the application folder**

This was a sample connection string I had :

```
<add name="dbEntities"
 connectionString="metadata=res://*/dbModel.csdl|res://*/dbModel.ssdl|res://*/dbModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5;provider connection string=&quot;
 Data Source=|DataDirectory|\db.sdf;Password=xxxxxxx;Persist Security Info=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

--
The project will work as it is expected if I place the **database** and **entities**
in the same project,
But placing them in a different project and referencing the that project wouldn't help,
I got no errors but the context will remain null.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: where are you placing the config? the config must be in the entry point, in your case the windows forms project.

Comment: The config is also in the root, both the config and the edmx and database are all in the root, What is interesting for me is if I use one project solution it will work !

Comment: well the config will picked up by the assembly which is the entry point, not where the db is. If you add the config to your windows forms project, it should work.

Comment: I think I did this in my previous builds of the project and yes it should work that way, but how the set the database address proper way when the config is in the Entry(Main) project ?, add your next post as an answer to this question and I will mark it as an answer.

Comment: I prefer to have set a relative address, Is it possible to set this connection via code while the edmx is another project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so from the comments above, we've established the reason is it's not picking up the config because you've placed it in the root along with the DB.

The config will only be picked up by the entry point. Placing it in the the Windows form should fix this issue.

Comment: Dude, you are right, but what I asked in the comments was this : how the set the database address proper way when the config is in the Entry(Main) project ?

Comment: im not familiar with setting connection strings for edmx files. Im simply answer your actual question. Here's a good troubleshooting post ive found. maybe it can help you. http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/08/13/38628/ he suggests specifying the assembly explicitly;

Comment: Thanks trying to resolve this, I will mark this as the answer +1, The question which I asked again in the comments is apiece of this question, the reason I moved the config file into the user project was for testing purpose, and the link also you gave couldn't help with this cause here I'm working with 2 assemblies, anyway it will help others, thanks being evolved in this.